# isspace() only works for digits up to 8?

Tags: c++, whitespace, isspace

In my code :

```
cout << "Isspace 5 and 10 are " << isspace(5) << " and " << isspace(10) << endl;
```

gives 0 and 8. Why does isspace(10) not give 0 since 10 is not a white space?

Comment: Note that the space character has value 32, so isspace cannot only work for numbers up to 8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're supposed to pass characters to `isspace`, not integers.

```
isspace('5') == zero (false)
isspace(' ') == non-zero (true)
```

When you pass `5` and `10` you're asking it if the characters with ASCII values 5 (ENQ, some rarely used control code) and 10 (LF, line feed, AKA `'\n'`) are whitespace. ENQ is not whitespace, so `isspace` returns zero. A line feed is whitespace, so `isspace` returns a non-zero value.

Comment: Should "ENQ, line feed" just be "line feed"?

Comment: Might be useful to note that [documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/isspace) that specifies `int ch` usually means a character (hence the `ch`).

Comment: Seems to me isspace takes integers, to be interpreted as character codes. If someone said "pass foo() a character" I would expect type char.

Answer (score 2):

Because according to issspace(), 10 (0xa) is a whitespace character (newline/linefeed). See http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cctype/isspace/

Answer (score 1):

The numbers you are passing are being treated as ASCII characters' numerical representation. 10 is a newline character which is considered by the system to be a white space character.